# Link "sobre nós" no pé do site não foi traduzido

Tags: novo-recurso, internacionalização

O link "sobre nós" no pé do site (que fica junto com "ajuda", "blog", "chat", etc...) leva a uma página sobre a empresa. Esta ainda não tem nenhuma tradução.

Entendo que o site fala sobre a empresa StackOverflow e não sobre o site. Também notei que é a mesma página em toda a rede StackExchange.

Mas acredito que seria mais interessante se houvesse uma página com informações, mesmo que básicas em português com um link para a página atual em inglês.
Se isso não fosse possível, o link poderia rezar ["sobre nossa empresa (em inglês)"](https://stackoverflow.com/company/about) ou "[sobre nós (em inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/company/about)"

Comment: Acho melhor alguém da SE responder, mas como você disse, todos os sites (pelo menos o que eu tenho costume de acessar) levam ao mesmo endereço. Independente do site ou do idioma. Desde o [Photography](http://photo.stackexchange.com/) ao [Anime & Manga](http://anime.stackexchange.com/) levam ao mesmo lugar. Acho que é algo padrão da SE, mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: @Randrade acredito que de certa forma seja mesmo o padrão. Mas não é nada legal.

Answer (score 4):

*Apenas para dar enfase*, como você mesmo disse a página ["sobre nós"](https://stackoverflow.com/company/about) é sobre a empresa *Stack Overfow* (não se refere ao site *stackoverflow.com*, nem pt.stackoverflow ou outro), é uma página **institucional**, não tem porque traduzir ela pois não se refere a um site especifico, apesar de usar o stackoverflow.com como a fonte inicial de negócios, provavelmente através de parcerias e do [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab).

*Suponho* que talvez seja porque o publico alvo que a empresa deseja atingir **não** seja os participantes das comunidades, mas sim **outras empresas** e pessoas que **desejem trabalhar** com eles, então neste caso o inglês não é um empecilho, ela mostra coisas como:

- História da empresa
- Localizações físicas

Está página também leva a links como:

- Equipe: https://stackoverflow.com/company/team
- Administração: https://stackoverflow.com/company/management
- Contate-nos: https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact
- Trabalhe aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here
- Calcular salário: https://stackoverflow.com/company/salary/calculator

Talvez se um dia houver uma sede no Brasil ou em Portugal então seja interessante dedicar uma página com o idioma do país, mas é quase certo que ela será indiferente ao site pt.stackoverflow.com (claro que vai depender da motivação).

O que acho que poderia ser feito seria uma postagem no *meta.pt.stackoverflow.com* com um pouco da história da empresa. Existe até um link no wikipedia https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow, mas não fala sobre a empresa e sim sobre o site stackoverflow.com.

Comment: É acredito que seja *by design*, mas não posso afirmar

Comment: Eu acredito que na verdade, não viram a necessidade pra fazer essa alteração. A rede foi lentamente crescendo com o tempo. Só de algum tempo pra cá houve essa preocupação com outras línguas. Ninguém realmente parou pra pensar: Peraí! Esse layout pode confundir quem se achega ao site via um dos sites menores.

Comment: @EMBarbosa acho que eles não tem preocupação nenhuma com outras idiomas, pelo menos não agora.

Comment: A propósito, não entendi o motivo de você ter alterado minha pergunta como se eu estivesse pedindo um novo recurso. A orientação do Gabe era pra deixar bug como tag.

Comment: @EMBarbosa veja bem, um bug seria uma falha que afete o site SOpt, no caso você esta pedindo uma página dedicada ao idioma português, então isto me parece um novo-recurso. Mas se desejar pode voltar a outra tag.

Comment: Entendi o ponto de vista. Por mim está bom assim mesmo.